# Centralizer of element in group PSL(2,F_p)

Tags: group-theory, classical-groups

Is it true, that $\forall g\in PSL(2,F_p)\setminus\{e\}$, $Z(g)$ is Abelian?

I think that this is true, but i can't find a simple proof.

Comment: I think before asking such a question on MO, you should check at least a few small cases whether you find a counterexample -- here you already find one at $p=7$. Voting to migrate to MSE.

Comment: This has been cross-posted to math.stackexchange anyway, so it probably should be closed here. The answer is no for $p>5$.

Answer (score 3):

This is false if $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$ (i.e. $p\equiv 1$ (mod. 4)). Then the homography $z\mapsto -z$ is in $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$, and its centralizer contains the homographies $z\mapsto \lambda z$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_p^{*2}$ and $z\mapsto 1/z$, which do not commute.

Comment: But $z\to -z=z\to z=e$ in $PSL(2,F_p)$. If i understend not correct, can you write your answer in matrix language.

Comment: What mean $z\to 1/z$?

Comment: abx identifies $PGL(2,\mathbb F_p)$ with the group of linear fractional maps from $\mathbb F_p\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself.

Comment: The group $\ \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)\ $ acts on $\ \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_p):=\mathbb{F}_p\cup \{\infty\} \ $ by $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\c & d\\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot z=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d} $ , and this action factors through $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$.